# How to list individual key values in an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm currently creating a table through React where the labels are certain object keys and the table entries are the object values. The set of data I'm using is an array of objects where I use `map` to get each individual object. Here's how I'm doing it.

```
{
  data.map(graph =>
    <div key={graph.ID} className="tables">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[0]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[1]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[2]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[3]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[4]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[5]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[6]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[7]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[8]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[9]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[10]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[11]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[12]}</th>
        <th>{Object.keys(graph)[13]}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[0]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[1]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[2]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[3]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[4]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[5]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[6]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[7]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[8]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[9]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[10]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[11]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[12]}</td>
        <td>{Object.values(graph)[13]}</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

As you can see, each entry on the table is a different key/value, and `graph` represents each individual object in the array. The problem is that some objects have more than 14 keys so I want to list out every key and value in each object within JSX regardless of the size. Does anyone know how to do that? I've tried using for loops (which is usually how I list out individual keys) but I can't seem to do that within JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.map()` for each row. For the `th` iterate the keys, and for the `td` use `Object.entries()` to get both the keys (for the item's keys) and values:

```
{
  data.map(graph => (
    <div key={graph.ID} className="tables">
      <table>
        <tr>
        {
          Object.keys(graph)
            .map(key => <th key={key}>{key}</th>)
        }
        </tr>
        <tr>
        {
          Object.entries(graph)
            .map(([key, val]) => <th key={key}>{val}</th>)
        }
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
{
  data.map(graph => {
    return (
      <div key={graph.ID} className="tables">
        <table>
          <tr>
            {Object.keys(graph).map(key => {
              return <th>{key}</th>
            })}
          </tr>
          <tr>
            {Object.keys(graph).map(key => {
              return <th>{graph[key]}</th>
            })}
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map()` method to do this:

```
<tr>
  Object.keys(graph).map((key) => (<th>key</th>))
</tr>
<tr>
  Object.values(graph).map((value) => (<td>value</td>))
</tr>
```

Note: this will most likely complain about absent `key` props, so you will have to add a key value to each element. (using the key value of `graph` object is one option)